# Can not get the code to compile: ')' expected 

Tags: java

I have reworked my java code for an Inventory program but, I still can not get the code to compile.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Television {

    private String itemNumber;
    private String productName;
    private double units;



    //constructor
    public Television (String itemNumber, String productName, double units, double unitprice) {
        setItemNumber(itemNumber);
        setProductName(productName);
        setUnits(units);
        setUnitPrice(unitPrice);

    }

    //accessor methods for class variables
    public String getItemNumber () {
        return itemNumber;
    }

    public void setItemNumber (String itemNumber) {
        this.itemNumber = itemNumber;
    }

    public String getProductName () {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName (String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public double getUnits () {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits (double units) {
        this.units = units;
    }

    public double getUnitPrice () {
        return unitPrice;
    }

    public void setUnitPrice (double unitPrice) {
        this.unitPrice = unitPrice;
    }

}
public class InventoryPart1 {

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat. getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);

        //create an instance of the Television class

        Television samsung = new Television ("SAMSUNG 46", "Class 6400 Series", 9.3,1,599.99);

        //use the methods from class Television to output the inventory details.
        System.out.println("Item Number: " + samsung.getItemNumber());

        System.out.println("Product Name: " + samsung.getProductName());

        System.out.print("Number of Units: " + samsung.getUnits());

        System.out.print("Unit Price: " + nf.format(Samsung.getUnitPrice()));

        System.out.print("Inventory______ Total:_______"+

  nf.format(samsung.calculateInventoryTotal());
```

I am receiving the following error:

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\AdminUser\MyDocuments\InventoryPart1.java:81:
>   ')' expected
>   nf.formatsamsung.calculateInventoryTotal));
>   ^ 1 error Tool completed with exit
>   code 1

Comment: It looks like you haven't posted all of the code - can you please do so? And also paste the compile errors that you are getting?

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\AdminUser\MyDocuments\InventoryPart1.java:81: ')' expected nf.formatsamsung.calculateInventoryTotal));                                                                   ^ 1 error Tool completed with exit code 1

Comment: @Raven50 - You can edit your own post and put the error in there. (I did it for you this time.)

Comment: I appreciate that I am new to all this, apologize.

Comment: Should be `String[] args`, not `String args[]`, in main (are you coming from C?). Easy way to remember it: it's an array of Strings, not args.

Comment: @Raven50 - No problem. :-) And, welcome to Stackoverflow. I know you'll find a lot of people here who are willing to help you out. Just to give you some starting advice - it's always good to provide as much information as you can (without going overboard) so we can better help you with your problem. It's also good to describe what you have already tried to do or how you've tried to fix your problem. And, of course, upvote answers and accept the answer that solves your problem. Thanks, and welcome to SO!

Comment: @Kevin Hikaru Evans: both compile and both work. In fact, I have no idea what the *actual* difference is between those two expressions, but I have not seen any evidence that the latter is wrong. Is there a reference that sheds light on this?

Comment: @poundifdef Wow, I never noticed that worked. I've been always taught to use `int[] arr` and I just assumed that `int arr[]` was wrong.

Comment: @Kevin Hiraku Evans yeah, i've always wondered about it too! But it is impossible to google due to all the punctuation.

Comment: Ah, there's something about it here: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/arrays-lev2.html

Comment: It looks like you are compiling by hand. If this is true, might I suggest downloading Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/downloads) or another IDE (Netbeans, IntelliJ).

Comment: @Kevin, poundifdef: The most common place that the different array syntaxes come into effect is when declaring variables: if you declare like `int[] a, b;` you'll get two `int` arrays `a` and `b`, but if you declare `int a[], b;` you'll get an `int` array `a` and a plain `int` `b`. Helpful to know if you have a habit of declaring multiple variables in a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following to compile your code, 
In your InventoryPart1 class.

1. Put this call for Television class, just remove one argument as the constructor have only 4 parameters: `Television samsung = new Television ("SAMSUNG 46", "Class 6400 Series", 9.3,599.99);`
2. Put one closing ')' as in above post suggested you are missing this: `System.out.print("Inventory______ Total:_______"+ nf.format(samsung.calculateInventoryTotal()));`
3. change spelling of Samsung to samsung here: `System.out.print("Unit Price: " + nf.format(Samsung.getUnitPrice()));`

And in your Television class change this things listed :

1. Put one instance variable `private double unitPrice;`
2. change spelling of your parameter name unitprice to unitPrice: `public Television (String itemNumber, String productName, double units, double unitprice) { ...}
3. Define one method as it calculates the total for you and return's totalAmt.`public double calculateInventoryTotal() {
       //calculate total here;
       return totalAmt;
   }`

Answer (score 6):

You are missing a parenthesis!

The last line should say:

```
System.out.print("Inventory______ Total:_______"+ nf.format(samsung.calculateInventoryTotal()));
```

(added a `)` character at the end)

Good luck!

In fact, that's exactly what the error was saying: `')' expected` means exactly that - the compiler was expecting a `)` character and it wasn't there! :)

Comment: I tried that also but then it said I had 5 errors instead of 1. I am so confused with Java

Comment: @Raven50 - See my post. It may help you out. (+1 for @poundifdef's answer as this solves the original problem)

Comment: This means that the java compiler was unable to see the other 5 errors until you fixed this one. If you're new to java I'd suggest using an IDE such as Eclipse or Netbeans. IDEs like these will highlight your problems as if it were a spelling mistake, and they will even offer hints on how to fix them.

Comment: @Raven50 Right. So the first error was a syntax error - missing a parenthesis. After fixing that, there are other problems with your code. But those problems aren't due to *syntax* (the correct placement of punctuation, etc.) Those are problems with whether or not you've declared variables properly, etc, which the compiler can only find if all the syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

- unitprice doesn't match unitPrice in Television constructor call
- unitPrice instance variable is missing
- Television needs to be declared public
- Television constructor doesn't match call in InventoryPart1 - one extra arg (or 1 missing param)
- samsung variable mispelled as Samsung in InventoryPart1
- calculateInventoryTotal method missing
- should be

  System.out.print("Inventory_ Total:**__**" + nf.format(samsung.calculateInventoryTotal()));

You would probably find all these problems right away if you were using a decent IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse.

I'm assuming that InventoryPart1 and Television are in separate files InventoryPart1.java, Television.java -- if not, they should be.

Comment: @Larry - You are right about using a decent IDE. However, in Raven's defense, many universities discourage the use of an IDE in early classes because it can become too easy to rely on their power and not actually learn the language.

Comment: My instructor has us using TextPad, is not really giving any concrete directions. I am trying to understand this part first since I have to do 5 other parts.

Comment: @JasCav -- you're probably correct, but IMHO very poor thinking on the part of the universities. Do the English profs discourage the use of spellcheckers .. math professors the use of calculators ..

Comment: @Raven50 -- I would get the IDE and keep it hidden from him :) I don't think I could program using TextPad (or wouldn't want to stay in the same career)

Comment: @Larry - Actually...I had a calc professor who didn't allow calculators. But, that is beside the point. I actually agree with you. While there are students who will use the IDE as a crutch and will never learn the language, NOT having a good IDE is holding back those students who could do so much more once they had it. (On the flip side, having to debug using the commandline and VIM taught me how to read error messages really quick.)

Comment: I'd hold off on the IDE for now. For someone who has never programmed, IDEs have such a huge learning curve that they distract from what ought to be a manageable two-class assignment. Plus, the professor may not be using an IDE to grade assignments, and it is easy to write code that is IDE-dependent. We're literally talking about the "order of operations" of programming here; no need for a calculator quite yet.

Answer (score 0):

As poundifdef pointed out (correctly), you are (first) missing a parenthesis. In your response, you say that you now get 5 errors instead of 1. So, I am more responding to that statement rather than your additional post.

One thing to possibly help you out in learning Java (because I made this same mistake when I was first beginning) is that the compile and runtime errors are EXTREMELY descriptive. I know seeing a ton of text come up on the screen can be intimidating, but take a second to read it and really parse what it says. Let's take a look at your current error (the parenthesis one).

> C:\Documents and
>   Settings\AdminUser\MyDocuments\InventoryPart1.java:81:
>   ')' expected
>   nf.formatsamsung.calculateInventoryTotal));
>   ^ 1 error Tool completed with exit
>   code 1

So, this is basically saying:

- InventoryPart1.java:81 - This is the line that your error is occurring on.
- ')' expected - So, you are missing a closing parenthesis. This indicates you will probably have to count the parenthesis on that line (or, more likely, in that statement) and figure out where you didn't properly close the parenthesis.
- nf.formatsamsung.calculateInventoryTotal)); - The compiler is showing you (approximately) where it thinks the problem is.

Once you have fixed this error, and you recompile, you may get more errors (and it sounds like you have from your other comments). The trick is to repeat the same process in parsing your errors and understanding what they are really saying. As was pointed out in another answer, a good IDE (Integrated Development Environment) such as [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) or [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) can do wonders in understanding your code and improving it. Other than that, it's a matter of stopping and spending some time thinking, "What is this error saying?" and "What is my code doing?" and "What am I really trying to do here?"

I know this didn't answer your question directly (and I did provide +1 to poundifdef) but I hope this does help you in your understanding of Java.

Comment: Thank you all for your input I will go back an go through this line by line. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @Raven50 - No problem. Happy to help. If poundifdef's answer did help you solve this particular problem, please make sure to accept it by checking the green check mark next to his answer.